# Loop through string - input as parameter [java]

Tags: java, string, loops, parameters

Let's say that i have a method goTo(int finalx, finaly, int currx, int curry) and a string that maybe looks like this:

```
String sequence = "0001112122"
```

The above means that 00->01->11->21->22

And this is how it should look like:

```
goTo(0,1,0,0);
goTo(1,1,0,1);
goTo(2,1,1,1);
goTo(2,2,2,1);
```

How can i write out the above using a foor loop maybe to iterate through the string an input the specific numbers at the right place?

Notice that sequence may not always be that specific length it could be a different sequence string.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
String sequence = "0001112122";
for(int i=0; i+3<sequence.length(); i+=2){
    int currx = Character.getNumericValue(sequence.charAt(i));
    int curry = Character.getNumericValue(sequence.charAt(i+1));
    int finalX = Character.getNumericValue(sequence.charAt(i+2));
    int finalY = Character.getNumericValue(sequence.charAt(i+3));
    goTo(finalX, finalY, currx, curry);
}
```

It parses the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th digit into your goTo() method then jumps forward two characters and repeats.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the purpose of your goTo method but you would definitely need to use the String charAt(int index) method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)